# CMake: how to clear target compile options

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

In my project I have defined some general compile options using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` globally. Some other options, that in common case should be applied to all targets, are specified using `add_compile_options()` in my main CMakeLists file.

For example I want the flag `-Wconversion` be applied to all targets.
But I have one external library that produces to many warnings with this option enabled. So I want to disable option only for this particular lib:

```
get_target_property(EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS ext_lib COMPILE_OPTIONS )
list(REMOVE_ITEM EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS -Wconversion)
set_target_properties(ext_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS ${EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS } )
```

But right now only `-Wconversion` was setted using `add_compile_options()`.
And target does not have any own additional flags. So, after removing the only entry from the list I will get an empty list. Call to set_target_properties() fails with error:

> set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

Is any way to clear some of target properties completly?
I'm using CMake 3.11

Comment: Just add quotes? `set_target_properties(ext_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "${EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS}")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Just add quotes:

```
set_target_properties(ext_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "${EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

Now - if `EXTLIB_COMPILE_FLAGS` variable is empty - you end-up having an empty string and just not an "missing argument".