# Override CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS per target

Tags: cmake

In a CMake C++ project which uses `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, how can I change or remove flags coming from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for a specific target?

I've tried the following, which doesn't remove the flags from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
# Set somewhere else in the project
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--bad-flag")

add_executable(main
    main.cpp
)

# Not actually removing the bad flag
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "")
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS ""
    COMPILE_OPTIONS ""
)
```

This question is related, but doesn't answer my question:
[Does set_target_properties in CMake override CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096881/does-set-target-properties-in-cmake-override-cmake-cxx-flags)

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239421/3987854) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216539/3987854) answer? These show how to *read* the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property for a particular target, modify the property, then **set** the updated property for the target. Note, `COMPILE_FLAGS` is deprecated and should *not* be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: how to clear target compile options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512905/cmake-how-to-clear-target-compile-options). This seems more directly related to your situation, in which you want to **remove** a *specific* flag for a specific target.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @squareskittles, I found an exact duplicate via one of your links. In the end, the easiest solution is to add the "opposite" flag to the target without removing anything, if it exists (e.g. `--no-bad-flag`).